# How to keep radio buttons on DispForm.aspx?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint list and the form is full radio button choices. For example, let's says one of my choice fields is comprised of "Option 1", "Option 2", and "Option 3". When a user selects a value and goes to view the form, it will show only the value that they have selected. However, I would still like the user to be able to see all 3 options when viewing the form. How can I have the list retain the radio button choices? Thank you!

BTW, right now I am using a custom form and am using this code that I found on the web as my JS file. Do I need to change something within here to make the dispform.aspx show the radio buttons?

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

.ms-formtable

{display:none;}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

    //loop through all the spans in the custom layout

    $("span.hillbillyForm").each(function()

    {

        //get the display name from the custom layout

        displayName = $(this).attr("data-displayName");

        elem = $(this);

        //find the corresponding field from the default form and move it

        //into the custom layout

        $("table.ms-formtable td").each(function(){

            if (this.innerHTML.indexOf('FieldName="'+displayName+'"') != -1){

                $(this).contents().appendTo(elem);

            }

        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Open Site in Designer->Click on List and libraries in left Pane->click on List for which you want to make modification--> Click on 'New' in form section->Enter name->Select form type as display form->Set this form as default form.->Right click on the form-->Click on edit file in advance mode-->Find required field controls "SharePoint:FormField"-->Change the value of `Controlmode` attribute form "Display" to "Edit" Or Replace control for following control.

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="FieldInternalName" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="FieldInternalName" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u','FieldInternalName','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@FieldInternalName')}"/>
```

Replace "FieldInternalName" with your internal name of field.

Once you add control on form Using jQuery disable this control.

Comment: <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="FieldInternalName" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="FieldInternalName" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u','FieldInternalName','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@FieldInternalName')}"/>

Answer (score 0):

Javascript approach can also help as below :

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var fieldTitle="test";
    var currentFieldValue=$(".ms-h3.ms-standardheader:contains('"+fieldTitle+"')").parent().next()[0].innerText.trim();
    var fieldHTML=GetFieldChoices(currentFieldValue,fieldTitle);
    $(".ms-h3.ms-standardheader:contains('"+fieldTitle+"')").parent().next().html(fieldHTML);
});
function GetFieldChoices(currentFieldValue,fieldTitle){
    var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace("{","").replace("}","");
    var fieldHTML="";
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'"+listId+"')/fields?$select=Choices&$filter= Title eq '"+fieldTitle+"'";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {       
            var choices = data.d.results[0].Choices.results;
            $.each(choices,function(index,choice){
                if(choice==currentFieldValue){
                    fieldHTML+="<input type='radio' disabled='disabled' checked='checked' name='"+fieldTitle+"' value='"+choice+"'>"+choice;
                }else{
                    fieldHTML+="<input type='radio' disabled='disabled' name='"+fieldTitle+"' value='"+choice+"'>"+choice;
                }
                if(index<choices.length){
                    fieldHTML+="<br>";
                }
            });         
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
    return fieldHTML;
}</script>
```

Just provide your field name in example above is `test` to your field and add this script on your display form using content editor.

Comment: So if the title of my column is 'AP Coding', do I just add that where test is?

Comment: Yes to above code snippet just replace your column title